# Doing black magic but you did not know shirk was a sin

Tags: shirk, forgiveness, kufr, doubts

When I was around in middle school I did black magic but I never heard of the sin shirk or black magic when I heard the news I asked Allah for forgiveness and I sincerely promised not to do it again will I be held accountable and I took the shahada again

Comment: You didn't know about shirk so you are not sinful, allah will not punish you, you don't need to be worry

Answer (score 1):

Assalam o Allaikum.

If you do not know that a certain act is prohibited in Islam then there is no sin upon you. In Islam, sin is based on the acts that we do willingly with knowledge of what religion says about it.

In Surah Al-An'am Ayat 54 Allah (subhanahu wa ta'ala) clears states:

> When those come to thee who believe in Our signs, Say: "Peace be on
> you: Your Lord hath inscribed for Himself (the rule of) mercy: verily,
> **if any of you did evil in ignorance**, and thereafter repented, and amend (his conduct), lo! He is Oft-forgiving, Most Merciful.