# Is making joke about dajjal and shaytan and mocking dajjal dan shaytan is kufr?

Tags: kufr

Is making joke about dajjal and shaytan or mocking them is kufr?
Example : (dajjal is stup**)

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, because you are not doing any kind of acts which is considered Kufr. The type of acts which considered kufr are given in details in [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/is-x-kufr-reference-question).