# Is Asking Parents Shirk or Kufr?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, kufr, parents

Assalamu Alaikum

My Question is asking parents kufr or shirk?

Or am I asking for my right?

Like if i need extra fees for supply exam.
Or need to buy a laptop.
Need prove with Quran o Hadith.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "X" kufr (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/is-x-kufr-reference-question)

Comment: Your parents are in charge for you as a child it's your right asking them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no verse or Hadith saying that you should not ask your parents for support. Anybody may ask anyone for support. The only regulation is that family support and support for persons that are not really in need doesn't count as Zakât.

I suppose that your question is about allowance only.
Please look up the meaning of Kufr and Shirk.