# Am I a kafir if I get married to a non Muslim man?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim, love

I am a Muslim woman and I plan to get married to a man who is agnostic. I will not force him to become a Muslim but if he does then that’s good. If not, that’s okay to me too. I love him and I don’t want to force anything on him. My question is just if the marriage will be valid and will I still remain a Muslim?

Comment: Also see [Is "X" kufr ?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271).

Answer (score 1):

It is not permissible for a muslim woman to marry a non-muslim man. And the evidence for the prohibition of that by the following Qur’anic verses:
***{1}***
[......وَلَا تُنكِحُوا۟ ٱلْمُشْرِكِينَ حَتَّىٰ يُؤ ۚ وَلَعَبْدٌۭ مُّؤْمِنٌ خَيْرٌۭ مِّن مُّ....](https://quran.com/2/221)

**-->** [… Nor marry (your girls) to unbelievers until they believe: A man slave who believes is better than an unbeliever, even though he allures you. Unbelievers do (but) beckon you to the Fire. But Allah beckons by His Grace to the Garden (of bliss) and forgiveness, and makes His Signs clear to mankind: That they may celebrate His praise] [2:221]

***{2}***
[يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُوٓا۟ إِذَا جَآءَكُمُ ٱلْمُؤْمِنَـٰتُ مُهَـٰجِرَٰتٍۢ فَٱمْتَحِنُوهُنَّ ۖ..](https://quran.com/60/10).

**-->** [O ye who believe! When believing women come unto you as fugitives, examine them. Allah is best aware of their faith. Then, if ye know them for true believers, send them not back unto the disbelievers. They are not lawful for the disbelievers, nor are the disbelievers lawful for them] (Al-Mumtahinah 60:10).

Thus, it should be crystal clear that all Muslim jurists have unanimously agreed that this kind of marriage is forbidden.