# Is wearing clothes with names a Sin?

Tags: halal-haram, kufr

Is wearing clothes **with names** a Sin? I have heard that clothing with names is a glorification of non-believers. Does it mean that wearing clothes where there are names such as: jordan, d&g and others is Sin? **What if I can't buy another one yet?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "X" kufr (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/is-x-kufr-reference-question)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not say exactly this, although I have heard from many other sources that this is kufr.

Answer (score 1):

> Is wearing clothes with names a Sin? I have heard that clothing with names is a glorification of non-believers.

Wearing clothes with something written on them is not a sin, unless what's written promotes a sin (like let's drink with a beer above it). Some Ulama (mainly Ibn Baz and Ibn al-Uthaymin) believe that writings should not contain the world Allah or anything that might relates to the Sifat of Allah since the cloths might get dirty or contain Najasah at some point.

Note that the Prophet forbade any wearing eye-catching clothes if you are doing congregational prayer (Salat al-jama‘ah) since it might distract other prayers, see "it (the Khamisa) has distracted me from my prayer." [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/2/117).